# How can you have a new box but the previous boxes are not deleted?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want a box to be drawn in special situations when the strategy gives a short or long signal.
The code I wrote does this, but the previous boxes are deleted .

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uGZz.png)]

The code I wrote does this, but the previous boxes are deleted and only the last boxes are shown.
I want a box to be drawn wherever I had a long and short signal.
I don't know where the problem is that it only shows the last box.

```
if Box_bool and longCondition
    enter_box       = ta.valuewhen( longCondition, ((close+open)/2) , 0)
    Stop_box        = ta.valuewhen( longCondition, filt , 0)
    var Box_orginal_l = box.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, low, border_color = #2196f310)
    box.set_lefttop(Box_orginal_l, bar_index[1], enter_box)
    box.set_rightbottom(Box_orginal_l, bar_index + 40, Stop_box)
    box.set_bgcolor(Box_orginal_l, #5c1b24a5)

        var tp_up_l = box.copy(Box_orginal_l) 
    box.set_lefttop(tp_up_l, bar_index[1], enter_box )
        box.set_rightbottom(tp_up_l, bar_index + 40, (enter_box - ((Stop_box - enter_box) * rr_)))
    box.set_bgcolor(tp_up_l, #00ffb330)

if Box_bool and shortCondition
    enter_box       = ta.valuewhen( shortCondition ,((close+open)/2) , 0)
    Stop_box        = ta.valuewhen( shortCondition,filt , 0)
    var Box_orginal = box.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, low, border_color = #2196f310)
    box.set_lefttop(Box_orginal, bar_index[1], enter_box)
    box.set_rightbottom(Box_orginal, bar_index + 40, Stop_box)
    box.set_bgcolor(Box_orginal, #5c1b24a5)

        var tp_down_l = box.copy(Box_orginal)
    box.set_lefttop(tp_down_l, bar_index[1], (enter_box + ((enter_box - Stop_box) * rr_)))
    box.set_rightbottom(tp_down_l, bar_index + 40, enter_box)
    box.set_bgcolor(tp_down_l, #043b37a5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a box with the `var` keyword, only one box is created the first time the local block is executed.

```
var Box_orginal_l = box.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, low, border_color = #2196f310)
```

And on subsequent times, the box coordinates and background color are updated.

```
box.set_lefttop(Box_orginal_l, bar_index[1], enter_box)
box.set_rightbottom(Box_orginal_l, bar_index + 40, Stop_box)
box.set_bgcolor(Box_orginal_l, #5c1b24a5)
```

So, you can simply remove the `var` keywords (from [var](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#var) declaration to "[on each bar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#on-each-bar)" declaration).

Also, by default, only the last 50 boxes are visible on the chart, but you can increase that number to 500 ([see documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Limitations.html#line-box-and-label-limits)).